# ng serve fails in test project after linking local angular build with yarn ng-dev misc build-and-link

Tags: angular

I am trying to build the angular repo locally and test a change I made in a test angular app. I followed the steps in [DEVELOPER.md](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/docs/DEVELOPER.md) and was able to run `yarn ng-dev misc build-and-link ../test-app` successfully to link the locally built packages to my test app.

The problem is as soon as I have done this I can no longer ng serve my test app, it cannot find the locally built angular packages:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find package '@angular/compiler' imported from /home/some-user/projects/angular/dist/packages-dist/compiler-cli/bundles/index.js

Not sure if it is helpful but my platform is Windows 11 and I'm running everything in a WSL Debian container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node --preserve-symlinks node_modules/.bin/ng s
```

This worked for me. This appears to be a known issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46771#issuecomment-1180024873

Comment: There's also a PR to improve the documentation for DEVELOPER.md that is going through review, so if this solution doesn't work for you or if you want to add information, here's your chance to speak up on it

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/47421